# Error inserting special chars sqlite Android from .sql file

Tags: android, sqlite

When I install my app into my android device, I create the database using 2 assets:
create_database.sql
insert_data.sql

Theese files contains the CREATE TABLE scripts and the INSERTS.

When I insert a special char like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbgnrmltext (IDLANGUAGE, TXTEXT, TXKEY )VALUES( 1,'Bebé','AGE_BABY');
```

In my sqlite it´s stored "Beb|-" or something strange.

I use this for execute the INSERT.

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
String line = "INSERT INTO tbgnrmltext (IDLANGUAGE, TXTEXT, TXKEY )VALUES( 1,'Bebé','AGE_BABY');"
mDatabase.execSQL(line);
```

When i access sqlite vía adb shell and uptate the string to 'Bebé' it´s correctly saved.

¿What can I do to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: How are you reading the SQL file? That's where the encoding is misinterpreted.

Comment: Did you use the Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: The problem became from the viewer: Windows console.
After setting all my eclipse project to use UTF-8, the app is shown correctly in mobile, but fails in windows console. So, problem gone.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes and escaping them in your query.

```
String line = "INSERT INTO tbgnrmltext (IDLANGUAGE, TXTEXT, TXKEY )VALUES( 1,\"Bebé\",'AGE_BABY');"
```